GEE Temporal Collection Landsat 8 C2L2T1 : Error: map(ID=0) Image.multiply: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1
I am struggling with an Error of missing Bands from a temporal Landsat8_C2_L2_T1 Image Collection while retrieving the temperature over a time range.(tried it with 1 year and 10 years. same problem.)
1st Error:
In the Image Collection I filtered (LS8),  I see 233 possible Images and every Image has one Band (ST_B10), that I selected. Everything is fine. When I want to create a temporal Composite/Collection for the Land Surface Temperature in the way that has been officially provided from GEE, I get the error message:

"Error in map(ID=0):
Image.multiply: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no >bands. Got 0 and 1.

The result variable "Landsat_Monthly" shows 12 images, where some has no band and others do.
I tried some of the solutions from similar questions here on the plattform and also some debugging from GEE - but none of them worked for me.
2nd Error:
When I try to find out the Aquisition Times for the Landsat Collection with the Image ID and convert it to standard Format, the images all have the problem of showing:

"- Acquisition Date and Time: undefined"

I tried it with different time ranges, same error for both issues.
At the end of the Code you find the links to the codes, that I rely on. In between I marked the Steps where the errors occur.
Can Someone provide help, please?
And sorry for possible formatting mistakes while writing here. It is my first question on stackexchange.
//Step 1: Access your boundary-defining geometry
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1")
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Brandenburg'));

// Set Time Range for landsat 8 image collection

var time_start = '2013-04-22', time_end = '2024-04-22'

//Import Image Collection for Landsat 8 and print it to console

var LS8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
  .select('ST_B10')
  .filterDate(time_start, time_end)
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10))
  .sort('system:time_start');

print(LS8, 'LS8')

// Function for extracting and formatting aqusition times

var addFormattedDateTime = function(image) {
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).advance(2, 'hour'); // adjust to local time Germany (UTC+2)
  var formattedDateTime = date.format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  return image.set('formatted_date_time', formattedDateTime);
};


LS8.evaluate(function(col) {
  col.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    print('Image ID:', feature.id, ' - Acquisition Date and Time:', feature.properties.formatted_date_time);
  });
});

// Print aqusition times to console

var LS8_time = LS8.map(addFormattedDateTime);
print(LS8_time)

//--> HERE 1. ERROR: Acquisition Date and Time: undefined

//Convert Collection to monthly format (Temporal Composite)
//write a function named temporal_collection:

var temporal_collection = function(collection, start, count, interval, unit){ //count= wie viele monate, interval wie viele bilder pro monat
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var origin_date = ee.Date(start);
  return ee.ImageCollection(seq.map(function(i){
    var start_date = origin_date.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), unit);
    var end_date = origin_date.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), unit);
    return collection.filterDate(start_date, end_date).median() // get the median Image from each month of the merged collection
    .set('system:time_start', start_date.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', end_date.millis())
    }))
  };


//Wrap the temporal collection function to Landsat Image Collection

var Landsat_monthly = temporal_collection(LS8, time_start, 12, 1, 'month');

print(Landsat_monthly, 'Landsat_monthly') 
// --> HERE: 2nd ERROR: not all images have bands here anymore.

// Convert the digital Numbers of Thernal band into kelvin and degree celsius

var tempL8 = Landsat_monthly.map(function(img){
  var kel = img.multiply(0.00341802).add(149); //coverts digital number to kelvin
  var cel = kel.subtract(273.15); // coverts kel to celsius
  return cel
  .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end'])
});

print(tempL8, 'Temperature over months')

//Create a Test Chart
print(
  ui.Chart.image.series(Landsat_monthly, ROI, ee.Reducer.mean(), 100, 'system:time_start')
  )

Map.addLayer(tempL8.toBands().clip(ROI), [], 'temperature Landsat 8', false)


/*sources:
temporal collection: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9ffde3c713f4f5303759c09b836f4f20
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLFcyTt-das */


I will only answer on the part of your question you have attached code for.
You have quite aggressively filtered out images with ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10)). Enough so that there are months without any imagery.
When you call median() on an empty image collection, you get an image without any bands. Operations on such an image is where your error message comes from.
I see two options:

Be less aggressive in your cloud masking, or remove the filtering based on CLOUD_COVER altogether, to ensure you have imagery for all months. If you do this, you want to ensure you properly mask out clouds on a per-pixel basis.

Exclude the months without imagery in your analysis


To exclude months, you can add a property to each image with the band count, then filter out images without bands:
var temporal_collection = function(collection, start, count, interval, unit) {
  ...
  return ee.ImageCollection(seq.map(function(i) {

    ...
    var median = collection.filterDate(start_date, end_date).median()
      .set('system:time_start', start_date.millis())
      .set('system:time_end', end_date.millis())
    return median.set('bandCount', median.bandNames().size())
  }))
};

var Landsat_monthly = temporal_collection(LS8, time_start, 12, 1, 'month')
  .filter(ee.Filter.gt('bandCount', 0))

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7987a3d3e18d2528721fc413f6c4bfc4
